# How can I improve my query, using joins & improving performance?

Tags: aggregate, pivot, mysql-5.7

I have a really smelly query which I'm not sure how to simplify, this is quite an intensive query.  I have tried various union and inner joins in an attempt to simplify it and my biggest problem is getting around the following error:

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

My query below solves this but it is not very efficient.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

When a media item has been deleted, I wish to soft delete all products where that media is associated providing that product does not have any other media files associated.

**Schema**

```
+-----------+----------+
| entity_id | media_id |
+-----------+----------+
|       192 |        1 |
|       193 |        1 |
|       193 |        2 |
+-----------+----------+
```

- I have a composite **Primary Key** index on `entity_id` and `media_id`
- I have a Foreign Key constraint on `entity_id` to `product` table
- I have a Foreign Key constraint on `media_id` to `product_media` table

When I delete media *#1* I would like to be able to update entity_id *#192* to set `deleted_at` to the current timestamp.  I *DO NOT* want to update entity_id *#193* because another media is associated to it.

```
UPDATE product
SET deleted_at = NOW()
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT entity_id
    FROM product_media
    WHERE media_id = ?
    AND entity_id NOT IN (
        SELECT entity_id
        FROM product_media
        GROUP BY entity_id HAVING COUNT(media_id) > 1
    )
)
```

As you can see there are two sub-queries, the fact I have 1 sub-query is somewhat of a concern but having two I know i'm doing something wrong but I cannot think for the life of my how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra unnecessary subquery check, and your subquery seems to only return a rowset if there is a single value in it, so you may want to use `=` instead of `in`. You can achieve the same by doing this:

```
UPDATE product
  SET deleted_at = NOW()
WHERE id = (
    SELECT entity_id
    FROM product_media
    WHERE media_id = ?
    GROUP BY entity_id
    HAVING COUNT(media_id) = 1
)
```